# how use local scope with eval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a module JS where i use React

```
 import React from 'react'
```

My component

```
export default class TaskDetail extends Component {...
```

I have a a string that represents a code:

```
str=`props => {
  return React.createElement(.....
```

and I would use this code in a module JS like this:

```
const MyCustomWidget = eval(str)
```

so that one it would be equal to write:

```
const MyCustomWidget = props => {
  return React.createElement(.....
```

I use MyCustomWidget to create a custom element in react-jsonschema-form

the point of my question is:
in my module i have imported React  but i have error React is not defined
that is because the result of eval have another scope...
if i write on top of my module:

```
 window.React = React
```

it works! but I wouldn't want to use

It is possible use eval and use the scope of my module ? I would like to use my imported React variable in my module without use window.React=React

is possible?

Comment: Take a look here, it might help!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781285/specify-scope-for-eval-in-javascript

Comment: Just because something is possible, does not mean you should do it. Find another pattern that does not use eval.

Comment: Eval should really be avoided if possible, but this should be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43306962/3893820

Comment: Well, theoretically, but I wouldn't recommend it, just use `new Function( React, `return ${str}` )( React );`. Then React would be passed as a function parameter which would be available for your code internally. I don't know if anything else would go wrong though

Comment: Can't you create a local variable that is a function that returns the function you want? You can pass arguments to the outer function that can be used when the inner function executes. I really feel like `eval` is a bad solution here.

Comment: i recived the string  str from the backend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to experiment with it...

```
const evalInContext = a =>
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-new-func
    new Function('require', 'const React = require("react");' + a).bind(
        null,
        require
    );
```

See how they evaluate and run react code from a live editor in react-styleguidist 
https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/blob/34f3c83e76/src/client/rsg-components/ReactExample/ReactExample.spec.js

Once again, if you cannot 100% trust what you eval, don't do it.