# Is there a way to execute a JavaScript string as some functions? I'm using eval but it is not working

Tags: javascript, serenity-js

Is there a way to execute a JavaScript string as some functions? I'm using `eval` but it isn't working.

I'm trying this as I need to read values from a YML file for my serenity js test.

This is what I'm trying to do

```
this.data = "element1.element2" 
this.test1 = "safeLoad(readFileSync(`config/${this.fileName}.yml`, 'utf8'))";
console.log(this.test1)
console.log(`${this.test1}.${this.data}`);
```

And this is how I'm trying to execute the string

```
eval(`${this.testabc}.${this.data}`)
```

However, when I execute this, I'm having the following error:

```
ReferenceError: safeLoad is not defined
```

P.S.: If I execute the code normally (without eval) it works fine!

```
safeLoad(readFileSync(`config/${this.fileName}.yml`, 'utf8')).element1.element2
```

Does anyone know how to execute code like that as a string?

Comment: It's a scoping issue. You should probably check [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [JavaScript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp). Since it's impossible to know what `this` actually stands for within your question, all I can say with certainty is that it's looking for the `safeLoad` function in the wrong scope.

Comment: There are lots of reasons why not to do this (security), however I suspect safeLoad is out of scope for eval, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781285/specify-scope-for-eval-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you `import safeLoad` using es6 syntax.

If yes, when you use `babel` to transpile code, `safeLoad` will be omitted. Because the transpiler though that safeLoad will not be used on your code.

To understand, please check the bellowing picture, or [this babel example](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAZwIYDMCmAZCSAmcVQQhwDky6ANtjiQFBoBuSFAFGaptSwJQndA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=typescript%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=Node-8.9&version=7.7.7&externalPlugins=).

[image]

To fix this, you should use `require` instead of `import(es6)`:

```
// instead of
import safeLoad from 'safeLoad'
// use this:
const safeLoad = require('safeLoad').default

// instead of
import { safeLoad } from 'safeLoad'
// use this:
const { safeLoad } = require('safeLoad')
```