# JavaScript extending the eval() function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, eval

I'm trying to make my own eval function in JavaScript, which will execute a string in the surrounding context, like eval, plus add a few more things.

So, in general, when doing:

```
eval("var foo = 8");
foo; // === 8
```

No problem; however, when I want to extend `eval` with my own function, like so:

```
function myEval(str) {
    return eval(str);
}
myEval("var foo = 8");
foo; //error, "foo" is not defined etc.....
```

And the obvious reason is because in myEval, the eval function called is only executed in that function's scope, not the surrounding scope.

**I was wondering if its possible to execute eval in the scope it's surrounding function was called, in order to extend the JavaScript function eval?**

Comment: No, there are only two scopes that `eval` can affect/be called in: The current scope or the global scope (via indirect `eval`).

Comment: Is this asked purely out of curiosity, or do you intend to actually use this? My respective comments on those situations are "hmm, I don't think so, but interesting question" and "why in God's name would you want to do this, or indeed touch `eval` in the first place?"

Comment: If you are using `eval` anyways, why don't you do a pattern of `eval(myEval(str))` instead? `myEval` can then produce arbitrary code executed in the current context, and prepend code, alter `str`, etc. (as others already mentioned though, eval = evil, but that's for you to decide)

Comment: I warned you `eval` has many pitfalls...

Comment: @VLAZ lol, this is in response to your answer, I was trying to bypass the problem of parameter passing, see other question's edit in a few seconds

Comment: @FelixKling see answer here, anything's possible

Comment: @ASDFGerte that's kind of what was ended up being done, but yes that's a good idea (see answer)

Comment: @bluejayke: That's the indirect `eval` call I was talking about. The code passed to `eval` is evaluated in global scope.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh I didnt realize thats what u meant, cool then, I guess thats the answer

Comment: To be clear though, global scope is not the same as the scope that calls `myEval` (unless `myEval` is called from global scope of course). But if you want that, the implementation can just be `function myEval(str) { window.eval(str); }`

Comment: @FelixKling oh no, I mainly wanted it in the scope that calls it, not globa, but thanks tho

Comment: Or `function myEval(str) { (1, eval)(str); }` for that matter. But it's not what the question asks for.

Comment: @ASDFGerte oh I realized that makes it executed on the global context as well, is there a way to only do it in the context it was called?

Comment: As has been commented at the very beginning, no.

Comment: @ASDFGerte think again https://stackoverflow.com/a/40268022/2016831

Comment: It's nice, that you are experimenting and learning, but i don't know why you feel the need to constantly claim it does something, which it doesn't.

Comment: @ASDFGerte what do u mean? my main point is to be able to declare variables as an expression, not a statement, while using arguments, `so eval(str(
    \`
      var x
    `,
    `
      x = args[0];

    \`
  ))({hi:"there"});
console.log(x)`
works

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, just wrap the eval function in another function, and call that other function in the surrounding scope, like so:

```js
function g(str) {
    return {
        eval,
        go(){
            this.eval(`
              //some other cool stuff
              let test = 1000;
              ${this.str}
            `)
        },
        str
    }
}
g("var pp = 3 * test").go()
console.log(pp);
```

EDIT:

this actually accomplishes it:

```js
function str(cod1,cod2) {
    return `
        ${cod1};
        (function(...args) {
            ${cod2}
        })
    `
}

function scope1() {
  eval(str(
    `
      var x,
          y,
          z
    `,
    `
      x = args[0];
      y = args[1];
      z = args[2];

    `
  ))(1, {test(){return "ing"}}, {ok:"string"})
  console.log(x,y.test(),z, "scope1");
}

scope1();

try {
  console.log(x, y, z);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: This just executes the code in the global context, it's an indirect eval call. It does not do what the question asks for.

Comment: @ASDFGerte the point of the question is to write a function that calls an more advanced, extended eval call, in the same context it was called. So instead of `eval("let k = 5; console.log(k)");` one could instead do, in that same context: `myEval(console.log(k))` with the `k` variable already defined, or many other variables already defined

Comment: `(function f() { let k = 0; g('let k = "myValue";').go(); console.log(k); })();`

Comment: @ASDFGerte Whats the question?